# In Ruby, how can I convert this string format to a hash

Tags: ruby

The string format is like this

```
 "a.b.c = 1"
 "a.b.d = 2"
=> its hash will be
=> {'a'=> {'b' => {'c'=>1, 'd'=>2 } } }
```

It gets tricky with arrays

```
 "a.e[0].f = 1"
 "a.e[0].g = 2"
 "a.e[1].h = 3"
 => its hash will be
 => {'a' => {'e' => [{'f'=>1, 'g'=>2}, {'h'=>3}] } }
```

I wrote a version which doesn't handle arrays with too many if-else checks

```
def construct
  $output[$words[0]] = {} unless $output.has_key?($words[0])
  pointer = $output[$words[0]]
  $words[1..-2].each do |word|
    pointer[word] = {} unless pointer.has_key?(word)
    pointer = pointer[word]
  end
  pointer[$words[-1]] = 1
end

$output = {}
$words = ['a', 'b', 'c']
construct
$words = ['a', 'b', 'd']
construct
p $output
```

The array version is even worse. Is there a better way of solving this in Ruby?

Comment: When you say string, did you mean you have string object as: `"a.b.c = 1"`?

Comment: `a.b.c` is a `c` method called on a return value of a `b` method called on an `a` object. Is that what you meant by 'string format'?

Comment: yes this line is a string "a.b.c = 1". It represents a key value pair where a.b.c. needs to be translated to a hash and 1 will be its value. updated my question. after evaluation its {"a" => {"b" => {"c" => 1}}}

Comment: I think it can be done with mechanical grouping symbols at each dot level and formatting the output with braces, arrows and commas, but am not sure of the level of generality you expect.  Should a solution be able to handle "a.b.c....z = n" and situations where all the input strings do not have the same number of dot-separated components?

Comment: yes the dot separated component can be in any number. even this is possible "a.b.c[2].d[0].e = 1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as simple as I did expect. Here is what I came up with:

```
class Hash
  def hash_merge(other)
    update(other) do | key, val_self, val_other |
      case val_self
      when Hash
        val_self.hash_merge val_other
      when Array
        val_self += [nil] * (val_other.length - val_self.length)
        val_self.zip(val_other).map { | a, b | a && b ? a.hash_merge(b) : a || b }
      else
        # error
      end
    end
  end
end

# parses a string of the form "a.e[1].g = 2" to a hash {"a" => {"e" => [nil , {"g" => 2}]}}
def construct_string(s)
  if s =~ /\A\s*(\S+)\s+=\s+(\d+)\z/
    s1, s2 = $1, $2
    s1.split('.').reverse.inject(s2.to_i) do | hash, name |
      if name =~ /\[(\d+)\]\z/
        name, idx = $~.pre_match, $1.to_i
        array = []
        array[idx] = hash
        { name => array }
      else
        { name => hash }
      end
    end
  else 
    # error
  end
end

# parses an array of string and merges the resulting hashes
def construct(s)
  s.map { | e | construct_string(e) }.inject(&:hash_merge)
end

ins = ["a.e[0].f = 1",
       "a.e[0].g = 2",
       "a.e[1].h = 3"]

p construct(ins)   # {"a"=>{"e"=>[{"f"=>1, "g"=>2}, {"h"=>3}]}}
```